# Authenticating People API without UI

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, service-accounts, google-people-api

I want to authenticate personal google account for people API to send get/post requests,

However, I have to avoid authenticating for API each time as there will a cron job using the API. One way is to authenticate the first time and then use the  refresh token for the necessary requests until the account revokes access (by changing password or manually removing the permission console)

Could there be a way, such that I could avoid manual authentication completely since the cron job will run on server-side

Used Service account for the same but didn't get required results

Comment: You tried using the service account? What didn't work about it?

Comment: Service account creates account as a dummy user i.e It has Its own drive due to which I  am getting empty list on get request.
I need to hit a get/post request on my own emailid in which all of my data(contacts) is already present

Comment: Yes, if you want the service account to act on behalf of a user (you) you need to delegate it domain wide access, so that it can impersonate you. See more https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en

Comment: @Aerials I followed that link. so, would he need a google workspace account for delegating it to domain-wide access, or I can do it with my personal account as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

You can give your application consent once (the first time), and set in the authorization parameters the optional `access_type='offline'`.

"Set the value to offline if your application needs to refresh access tokens when the user is not present at the browser. This is the method of refreshing access tokens described later in this document. This value instructs the Google authorization server to return a refresh token and an access token the first time that your application exchanges an authorization code for tokens."